# JSON API - send PDF file - TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, rest, pdf, binary

I'm trying to send a `pdf` file to [sendpulse API](https://sendpulse.com/integrations/api/smtp)

I can send `txt` files but there is a problem with sending `pdf`.

```
    import base64

    def fn():
        value = None
        with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'rb') as f:
            value = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()


        payload = {"email": {
                    "subject": "Test",
                    "template": {
                        "id": tmplt_id,
                        "variables": context,
                    },
                    "from": {
                        "name": 'myname.sk',
                        "email": sender_email
                    }, "to": [{
                        "email": r,
                    } for r in recipients],
                    'attachments':
                        {
                           'test.pdf':value
                        }

                }
                }
        return requests.post('https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails', headers=self.get_request_headers(),
                             json=payload)
```

If I use `value = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()`, it works but `pdf` file can't be open so it's corrupted.

If I don't append `.decode()`, it raises `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

If I use `'r'` mode instead `'rb'`, it raises `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Do you know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `attachments_binary` with your base64-encoded data instead of `attachments`.

Comment: I was planning to do that but then I forgot :) Thanks